# How to send text data on Gmail inbox?

Tags: java, android, string, gmail, inbox

I want to create an app for myself that, pressing a button, uploads some text on my Gmail. My app would work like this:

1. I have my text in a String var
2. I push a button
3. The app checks if the "myappnameFolder" already exists in my Gmail inbox
4. The app sends to my mail address an email with the content of the String var

The problem is that I don't know how to connect my app with Google inbox and how to send myself an email. Is this possible? I've already seen some articles on connecting Google+ account but I didn't find any solution.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you will need to use the Google API Client Library. To learn how to access the Google API with java [read here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/)

The java api documentation on gmail labels is [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels)